# Filtering and splicing an array in Twig

Tags: php, arrays, twig, silex

I have an array of user records (0 indexed, from a database query), each of which contains an array of fields (indexed by field name). For example:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Fred
            [age] => 42
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Alice
            [age] => 42
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Eve
            [age] => 24
        )

)
```

In my Twig template, I want to get all the users where the `age` field is 42 and then return the `name` field of those users as an array. I can then pass that array to `join(<br>)` to print one name per line.

For example, if the age was 42 I would expect Twig to output:

```
Fred<br>
Alice
```

Is this possible to do in Twig out of the box, or would I need to write a custom filter? I'm not sure how to describe what I want in a couple of words so it may be that someone else has written a filter but I can't find it by searching.

Comment: something like this https://twigfiddle.com/ljb4h5 ?

Comment: As mentioned on the answer below, that doesn't give me the same functionality as `join` as it will place the glue string after every element, rather than all but the last element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Final solution was a mix of what has been posted so far, with a couple of changes. The pseudocode is:

```
for each user
  create empty array of matches
  if current user matches criteria then
    add user to matches array
join array of matches
```

Twig code:

```
{% set matched_users = [] %}
  {% for user in users %}
    {% if user.age == 42 %}
      {% set matched_users = matched_users|merge([user.name|e]) %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  {{ matched_users|join('<br>')|raw }}
```

`merge` will only accept an `array` or `Traversable` as the argument so you have to convert the `user.name` string to a single-element array by enclosing it in `[]`. You also need to escape `user.name` and use `raw`, otherwise `<br>` will be converted into `&lt;br&gt;` (in this case I want the user's name escaped because it comes from an untrusted source, whereas the line break is a string I've specified).

Answer (score 7):

You can apply a filter on the array you apply for loop on, like this:

```
{% for u in user|filter((u) => u.age == 42) -%}
   <!-- do your stuff -->
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 6):

In twig you can merge the for ( .... in ....) with the if condition like :

```
{% for user in users if user.age == 42 %}
    {{ user.name }}{{ !loop.last ? '<br>' }}
{% endfor %}
```

Edit: This syntax is deprecated, and we are advised to use `|filter` as a replacement for the `for...if` syntax.

[Twig Filter: filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/filter.html) (The name of the filter is filter)

[Twig Deprecated Features](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/deprecated.html)

Comment: This isn't exactly what was asked as the last line should not have a `<br>`.

Answer (score 2):

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% if user.age == 42  %}
        {{ user.name|e }}<br>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

in alternative you can create an array of elements

```
{% set aUserMatchingCreteria %}
{% for user in users %}
    {% if user.age == 42  %}
        {% aUserMatchingCreteria = aUserMatchingCreteria|merge(user.name) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{{ aUserMatchingCreteria|join('<br>') }}
```

Comment: You can just do it with `{% for user in users if user.age == 42 %}` Here is the [doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition)

Comment: That's not quite as elegant as `join` as I have to remember not to include the final glue element (I want `<br>` after every name except the last), and `loop.last` explicitly doesn't work with a condition. Since I don't know how which element will be last I'm not sure I can solve my problem this way?

Comment: your answer is good but no where is there a standart for `</br>` like this. You better use `<br>` or `<br/>` but not `</br>`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, for several reasons:

1. `{% set aUserMatchingCreteria %}` isn't valid (you have to use `{% set aUserMatchingCreteria = [] %})`

2. You can use `merge` with a string as the argument, it has to be an array. `[user.name]` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Since Twig 2.10, the recommended way to conditionally exclude array elements is [the `filter` filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/filter.html). As was noted in some previous answers, `loop.last` has some issues, but you can simply flip the logic and use `loop.first`, which will work consistently:

```
{% for user in users|filter((u) => u.age == 42) %}
    {{ loop.first ?: '<br/>' }}
    {{ user.name|e }}
{% endfor %}
```