# Last iteration on For loop with If condition with twig

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, if-statement, twig

So this is only an example of what I'm trying to achieve.
I'm looping through all items and print only those, who starts with F and separate them with comma.So in the end, the loop will made, for example 15 iterations, but will print only 5.I'm trying to catch the last one that will be printed, so I can remove the comma.I tried with the filter loop.last, but it works only if the loop print the last item, but if the last print was earlier, it's still with comma.

```
{% for item in items %}
  {% if item starts with 'F' %}
     {{ item }},
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I can't edit anything from items.
Please help, I'v been stuck on this from a while.

Comment: Assign/append the text (including the comma) to a variable as you loop (instead of outputting). After the loop, strip the last character (the trailing comma). Then output.

Comment: Filter the items before the loop.

Comment: Use implode like function

Comment: Using it in if statement doesn't work, because the last item is always the last iteration and not always the last one will be printed, so it will not target.

Comment: Implode is equivalent of the filter |join(' ') right? I think I'v tried it and it doesn't work.

I don't have access to items.

What's the proper way to strip it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering and splicing an array in Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41702618/filtering-and-splicing-an-array-in-twig)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this, so I thought I would provide an answer:

```
{% set items = ['Fitem1', 'item2', 'Fitem3', 'Fitem4', 'item5'] %}
{% set newArray = [] %}
{% for item in items %}
  {% if item starts with 'F' %}
    {% set newArray = newArray|merge([item])  %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{{ newArray|join(',') }}
```

Comment: your sotutions work fine! Take a look at my answer that don't need the array definition

Answer (score 8):

A more simply solution could be [Adding a condition](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition) to the for statement and display the comma only if is not the first interaction (`loop.last` is defined when using loop conditions). As example:

```
{% set items = ['Fitem1', 'item2', 'Fitem3', 'Fitem4', 'item5'] %}

{% for item in items if item starts with 'F'%}

{% if loop.first == false  %},{% endif%}
{{item}}

{% endfor %}
```

See [this twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/k86ymg) for the working solutions

Comment: That works fine too, although I had a few words to put outside the loop as well, so I used the solution with the array.Thanks for the alternative, will help me for sure in the future. :)

Comment: Dang and here I thought you couldn't use `loop.first` with a condition because `loop.last ` can't be used when using one... +1