# Twig If statement within for loop opening tag

Tags: twig, php-7.2, symfony5

I have this code that is supposed to count items in a for loop retrieved from an object.
This code is running on a symfony 5.0 project with php 7.2.5 and twig-bundle 5.0

```
{% set sent_mails = 0 %}

 {% for email in emails if email.status == 1 %}
    {% set sent_mails = (sent_mails + 1) %}
 {% endfor %}

{{ sent_mails }}
```

and it gives the following error:

[image: Symfony error message]

When I run this same code on Symfony 4.2 using php 7.1.3 and twig-bundle 4.2, everything works without an error.

[image]

is there any change to the twig-bundle code syntax that I am not using correctly or what am I missing?

Comment: Just put the IF in its own instrution

Comment: "symfony/twig-bundle": "5.0.*" from composer.json that why I said twig-bundle 5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way of achieving this by using filter as recommended by Twitter user: @dbrumann

```
{% set sent_mails = 0 %}
   {% for email in emails|filter(email => email.status == 1) %}
    {% set sent_mails = (sent_mails + 1) %}
   {% endfor %}

{{ sent_mails }}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
{% set sent_mails = 0 %}

{% for email in emails %}
    {% if email.status == 1 %}
        {% set sent_mails = (sent_mails + 1) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{{ sent_mails }}
```

Comment: yes, this will work but is this a clean and efficient way of doing it?

Comment: What's not efficient ? You have a loop and a condition to know how many mail you sent, what's wrong ? Here is an other question that looks like yours : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41702618/filtering-and-splicing-an-array-in-twig

Answer (score 3):

Using an `if` inside a `for` is deprecated:

> Using an "if" condition on "for" tag in "main.twig" at line 1 is
>   deprecated since Twig 2.10.0, use a "filter" filter or an "if"
>   condition inside the "for" body instead (if your condition depends on
>   a variable updated inside the loop).

[source](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/deprecated.html#tags)