# Filter for each

Tags: twig

I would like to add the following condition to my template but I don't know exactly how to write it correctly.

```
{% for service in services if service.serviceGroup.id == servicegroup.id %}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Twig If statement within for loop opening tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59154335/twig-if-statement-within-for-loop-opening-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{% for service in services|filter(v => v.serviceGroup.id == servicegroup.id) %}`

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/filter.html

Comment: Thank you so this works; but what does the "v => v." mean?

Comment: That is part of the function. please see the docs I linked.

Comment: I have, but there is also no explanation why it has to be written like this
so it is extremely difficult for me to learn that if no reason is recognizable